# Accessing HTML elements from java

Tags: java, html

I need to access *HTML* elements from my *Java* program based on the id or className of the element (like `getElementByID` or `getElementsByClassName`). I also need to be able to click a few buttons on the page.

Main Points:

**I am creating a desktop application. It is not a web app.** 
**I need a browserless solution**
**My code needs to auto fill a form and submit it without opening a page.**

Are there any libraries out there that could suit my needs, or could I achieve this in plain *Java* code? If my question isn't clear please let me know and I will try to explain it in a better way. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using an applet?

Comment: Not clear!  What code have you written so far?  Are you screen scraping a site?  Are you using JEE?  What are you're requirements here?

Comment: I am not using an applet. @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a library used for scraping html elements using java. It is often used for testing. There is another library called Vaadin. It is used for doing front-end work on the back-end using java. It is similar to Java Swing but used on the web. Hope this helps!